# Words to compare two manners

Tags: word-request

Consider this sentence:

> A user does this task by scanning the page in a top-down and bottom-up manner. The algorithm for this task **(respectively ? )** traverses the tree  bottom-up and top-down...

In general, when you want to say a related task is done in the same manner, which words are used?

Comment: You need "traverse**s**" (3rd person singular).

Comment: If you use "respectively", put it at the end:  "The algorithm...traverses the tree bottom-up and top-down **respectively**..."   ( are you sure you have the "scan" actions and the  "traverse" actions in corresponding order?")

Comment: @BrianHitchcock no they are just similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "*similarly*", but something is missing from this fragment.

*Who* does the task?  A human looking at the page?  Perhaps you could combine what you're trying to say into a single sentence and explain that the algorithm is implemented following the *natural order* of performing such a task by a human.

Comment: "Similarly" sounds good. I modified my question, yes the first sentence is for a user